# Question about $\mathcal{\bar{\hat{X}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Denote $\mathcal{X}^*$ as the dual space of $\mathcal{X}$, i.e., the space of all bounded linear functionals on the normed vector space $\mathcal{X}$. For any $x\in\mathcal{X}$, define $\hat{x}: \mathcal{X}^*\to \mathbb{C}$ by $\hat{x}(f) = f(x)$, so then we have $\hat{\mathcal{X}} := \{\hat{x}: x\in \mathcal{X}\} \subset \mathcal{X}^{**}$.

Then in Folland's real analysis, I'm confused about the statement

> The map $x \mapsto \hat{x}$ embeds $\mathcal{X}$ into $\mathcal{\bar{\hat{X}}}$ as a dense subspace. $\mathcal{\bar{\hat{X}}}$ is called the **completion** of $\mathcal{X}$. In particular, if $\mathcal{X}$ is itself a Banach space then $\mathcal{\bar{\hat{X}}} = \hat{\mathcal{X}}$.

May I ask what "a map embeds A into B as a subspace" means? 
Why is $\mathcal{\bar{\hat{X}}}$ the **completion** of $\mathcal{X}$ despite that $\mathcal{\hat{X}}$ and $\mathcal{X}$ contains different objects (the former contains mappings while the latter contains vectors)?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $\hat{\mathcal{X}}$ is dense in its own closure is a tautology.

Now the map $x \mapsto \hat{x}$ is always an **isometry**, which, when $\mathcal{X}$ is Banach, forces its image $\hat{\mathcal{X}}$ to be closed in $\mathcal{X}^{**}$. You can check more generally that if $E$ and $F$ are Banach spaces and $T : E \to F$ is a bounded linear operator, $\|Tx\| \geq \alpha \|x\|$ for some $\alpha > 0$ if and only if $T$ is injective and its image is closed in $F$. Apply this to $T : x \mapsto \hat{x}$.

Comment: Thanks! For the first statement, I'm confused about why could $\mathcal{X}$ ever be a subspace of $\mathcal{\bar{\hat{X}}}$, since the former contains vectors while the latter contains mappings?

Comment: It is not really a subspace, the important term here is *embeds*. The continuous map $x \mapsto \hat{x}$ is injective, so we can identify $\mathcal{X}$ with its image $\hat{\mathcal{X}}$. The latter is indeed a subspace of $\bar{\hat{\mathcal{X}}}$.

Comment: Thanks! I have a further question: The book also says $\mathcal{\bar{\hat{X}}}$ is the **completion** of $\mathcal{X}$. May I ask why? I thought completion is the smallest complete metric space containing a given space, but I don't think $\mathcal{\bar{\hat{X}}}$ contains $\mathcal{X}$ here. How to understand this sentence?

Comment: If $\mathcal{X}$ is Banach (complete) then $\hat{\mathcal{X}}$ is closed in $\mathcal{X}^{**}$. Recall that in a complete space, closed subsets are exactly the complete metric subspaces. Hence if $\mathcal{X}$ is complete then $\bar{\hat{\mathcal{X}}}$ is also complete. Now if $\mathcal{X}$ is not complete, then we said we could see it as $\hat{\mathcal{X}}$ inside $\mathcal{X}^{**}$. The smallest **complete** subspace of $\mathcal{X}^{**}$ containing $\hat{\mathcal{X}}$ is exactly the smallest **closed** subspace of $\mathcal{X}^{**}$ containing $\hat{\mathcal{X}}$, that is, its closure !